# How to create free apple developer account to create ips file without provisioning profile in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, code-signing, apple-developer

I have apple developer account but which is not free.. I need free apple developer account to create ipa file with out provisioning profile.. to test app in real devise.

this is my apple developer account

[image]

when i register with this account in xcode-> prefrances -> account -> appleid

it showes like this

[image]

in the place of user i want free so that i can create ipa file without provisioning profile.

I am getting this error in xcode because of user

[image]

i am following this to create ipa file without provisioning profile

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gRp5Z0tpXM.

please help me to create free apple developer account.

Comment: Why do you want to create an IPA with no code signature? It won't run on the vast majority of iOS devices. It _might_ run on the small percentage of devices that have been jailbroken but that would be it. If you already have a paid account why limit yourself to a tiny fraction of devices?